# Difference of connection between JDBC4 driver and r2dbc driver

Tags: java, postgresql, r2dbc

While working on a Java application that connects to postgres DB, I encountered an error while using different database drivers.

The application connects to postgres DB 14.0 using

- A connection obtained via `javax.sql.Datasource` used for applying database changes via liquibase.
- The rest of the business logic was using reactor APIs and hence was using `r2dbc` driver to connect and execute any queries.

While running the application locally, both the mechanisms worked fine. However, when this was run on AWS using an RDS postgres 14.0 instance, I observed a different behaviour.

- The `Datasource` based part used by liquibase worked.
- The `r2dbc` part failed with the following error.

```
Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlAuthenticationFailure: [28000] no pg_hba.conf entry for host "*.*.*.*", user "devuser", database "devDB", no encryption
```

This got me thinking on why JDBC4 connection obtained by `Datasource` worked while `r2dbc` based connection was interrupted in its path and asked for client authentication by having host entry in its path.

Both the ways are using standard way to connect i.e. username, password, etc. No SSL or encryption was enabled, it was just using default settings.

Does anyone have any idea what may be the difference in the way these drivers connect? Why one of them is not challenged by database for client authentication while the other is?